# When I write code inside textbox doesn't accept it

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a textbox in a form. I use this textbox to write "Codes" and then I save it in the table in the database through the SQL insert statement, but the code doesn't accept to run and gives me an error message:
Run-Time error '3075'.

type of database: Access database
type of field data: LongText

What the problem and how to pass all same problems when I need to save codes inside the database field.

When I try to save the code without (') it's working!

I use this SQL Statement:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Update Tbl_Codes Set [LP_ID]= " & Me.txtID & ", 
[Code_Title]='" & Me.txtTitle & "'" _
& " ,[Code_Des]= '" & Me.txtDes & "',[Code_Key]= '" & Me.txtKey & "', 
[Notes]= '" & Me.txtNotes & "'" _
& " Where [ID]= " & Me.txtID1 & ""
```

And I want to save this Code:

```
DSum("Field1";"Table";"Field2=  '" & Value & "'")
```

Comment: Concatenation is always a bad idea and open invitation to SQL injection, use parameterized query instead, it will solve your problem and also save you from other issues.

Comment: You aren't running an INSERT statement, you show an UPDATE. Why do you reference txtID and txtID1? Are these both user input? You want to save a domain aggregate expression? The quote marks and apostrophes in the DSum() will cause issue. What is the content of Value? Value is a reserved word and really should not use reserved words as names for anything. Might be easier to open a recordset object and set field values that way.

Comment: @TaimurKhan
Please if you can give me an example of the parameterized query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code as follows. You need to escape single quotes by doubling them up. A simple replace will work for your.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Update Tbl_Codes Set [LP_ID]= " & Replace(Me.txtID,"'","''") & ", 
[Code_Title]='" & Replace(Me.txtTitle,"'","''") & "'" _
& " ,[Code_Des]= '" & Replace(Me.txtDes,"'","''") & "',[Code_Key]= '" & Replace(Me.txtKey,"'","''") & "', 
[Notes]= '" & Replace(Me.txtNotes,"'","''") & "'" _
& " Where [ID]= " & Me.txtID1 & ""
DSum("Field1";"Table";"Field2=  '" & Replace(Value,"'","''") & "'")
```

Comment: thank you but what if I faced the same problem with another code quote?

Comment: Please dig into dbs.CreateQueryDef to create a query dynamically using parameters.

Comment: If above solution solves your issues. Please accept it as answers.

Comment: could you please clear to me how I can do it? I mean db.createquerydef

Comment: Yes dear, I know about that, but I meant about "Please dig into dbs.CreateQueryDef to create a query dynamically using parameters."

Comment: Please see following forum for detail. https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=236021